# Why is this caesar encryption wrong when output looks correct?

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I have been doing the cs50 project 'Caesar' over the last few days and have managed to get it to a point of working in terms of visual output, however whenever I run the check50 that the course asks me to run it seems to keep giving me multiple errors that I cannot find directly as when looking at visual output it seems that it is the expected.

This comes from working in the cs50 IDE and following this project link:

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/caesar/

Here are the results as given by the cs50 check50 function:

```
>     :( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: b\...", not "ciphertext: b"
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 1...
>     sending input a...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: b\n"...
>     
>     Expected Output:
>     ciphertext: b
>     Actual Output:
>     ciphertext: b
>     :( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: yx...", not "ciphertext: yx..."
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 23...
>     sending input barfoo...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: yxocll\n"...
>     
>     Expected Output:
>     ciphertext: yxocll
>     Actual Output:
>     ciphertext: yxocll
>     :( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: ED...", not "ciphertext: ED..."
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 3...
>     sending input BARFOO...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: EDUIRR\n"...
>     
>     Expected Output:
>     ciphertext: EDUIRR
>     Actual Output:
>     ciphertext: EDUIRR
>     :( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: Fe...", not "ciphertext: Fe..."
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 4...
>     sending input BaRFoo...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: FeVJss\n"...
>     
>     Expected Output:
>     ciphertext: FeVJss
>     Actual Output:
>     ciphertext: FeVJss
>     :( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: on...", not "ciphertext: on..."
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 65...
>     sending input barfoo...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: onesbb\n"...
>     
>     Expected Output:
>     ciphertext: onesbb
>     Actual Output:
>     ciphertext: onesbb
>     :( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
>     expected "ciphertext: ia...", not "ciphertext: ia..."
>     Log
>     running ./caesar 12...
>     sending input world, say hello!...
>     checking for output "ciphertext: iadxp, emk tqxxa!\n"...
>     
>     
>     <<
```

Here is the code done in C with the cs50 libraries to allow easier functionality:

```
           //string validity
                     
            if (validity)
            {
                //prompt for plaintext
                string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
                printf("ciphertext: ");
                int n = strlen(plaintext);
                //calculate the encryption
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
                    {
                        printf("%c", (plaintext[i] - 'A' + KEY)  % 26 + 'A');
                    }
                    else if (islower(plaintext[i]))
                    {
                       
                        printf("%c", (plaintext[i] - 'a' + KEY) % 26 + 'a');
                    }
                    else if( ispunct(plaintext[i]) || isspace(plaintext[i]))
                    {
                        printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
       }
    }
```

I believe the problem is in the output part of the code which is above, I would greatly appreciate the assistance

Comment: `checking for output "ciphertext: yxocll\n"...` Notice that last `\n` in the expected output. Are you sure you print that?

Comment: Thank you so much i completely overlooked that. seems so simple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from comments from 'Some programmer dude'

It turned out that I had to print the last '\n' in the output to get it to work 100%